# Calculator code: ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python, calculator, valueerror

I am working on the pyhton calculator code below, but I keep getting an error message "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '". This error message occurs when I enter a value with one of the operators, such as "+".

I want the code to jump back to the printout ("This is not a number").
I use the following input:

```
`Enter value: +
 traceback(most recent call last):
    file "<string>", line 26, in module <module>
    File "<string>", line 10, in is_string
 ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Comment: your `is_string()` funtion takes in value as a parameter but you seem to be using val to make checks, while its not the cause of your issue its something you would want to fix

Comment: you should give us the exact input you are giving when the error is raised

Comment: Does this happen on all operators? If not or only one input you've provided, please show a [mcve]

Comment: So, you type only `+`, right? Then what is there to split or convert?

Comment: Your input was `+`. This expression: `float(val.split("+",1)[1])` splits that input string `"+"` into the list `["", ""]`. So the expression amounts to `float("")`. And, as the message says, an empty string isn't something that `float()` will accept.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the code to jump back to the printout ("This is not a number")

Catch a `ValueError` when you parse the input to a number

```
number = 0
while True:  
    print("Current value:", number) 
    val = input('Enter next value (or q to stop): ')
    if val == 'q':
        break
    try:
        val = int(val)
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a number")
        continue

    op = input('Enter operator: ')
    if op == '+':
        number += val
        

    print(number)
print('Final value:', number)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
number = 0

def is_string(value):
      if val[0] in '*+-/' : 
          return True
      print("There are no operator")
      return False

while True:  
      val = input('Enter value: ')
      if val[0] == 'q':
          exit()

      if is_string(val):
            if val[0] == '*':
                  number *= float(val.split(val[0])[1])
            elif val[0] == '/':
                  number /= float(val.split(val[0])[1])
            elif val[0] == '+':
                  number += float(val.split(val[0])[1])
            elif val[0] == '-':
                  number -= float(val.split(val[0])[1])    
            print(f'{round(number,2):g}')
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, please explain what you changed

Comment: A code dump isn’t very helpful, please explain.